# Java Rest Client - Need to add local Variable in URL

Tags: rest

Rest client.

Can I add a local variable for value into URL string for a Rest client ?

Example
URL testurl = new URL("http://X.X.X.X:7001/lab2.local.rest1/api/v1/status/database?rxnum=1111");

The above works if I provide literal value for rxnum (i.e. 1111).

But I need rest client to utilize value of a local variable.  exam

int rxvalue = 1111;

URL testurl = new URL("http://X.X.X.X:7001/lab2.local.rest1/api/v1/status/database?rxnum=+(rxvalue)+");

this doesn't work, obvious my  URL string is incorrect.  What is correct syntax to allow URL string to use value of local variable rxvalue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
URL testurl = new URL("http://X.X.X.X:7001/lab2.local.rest1/api/v1/status/database?rxnum=" +rxvalue);
```

Simple String concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not building the URL string correctly. It is always a good idea to log url/print to be sure that you are creating the correct url. The problem lies in the way you are trying to concatenate the rxvalue, here is the correction in your code :

```
String urlString = "http://X.X.X.X:7001/lab2.local.rest1/api/v1/status/database?rxnum=" + rxvalue;
URL testurlWithString = new URL(urlString);
System.out.println(testurlWithString);
```